# Prove that if $a_n>0$ and $\sqrt[n]{\sum_{k=n}^{n+20}a_k} \to l<1$ as $n\to+\infty$ then $\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k$ converges

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Prove that if $a_n>0$ and $\sqrt[n]{\sum_{k=n}^{n+20}a_k} \to l<1$ as $n\to+\infty$ then $\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k$ converges.

My try is:
$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k=\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} a_k+\sum_{k=n}^{n+20}a_k+\sum_{k=n+21}^{\infty}a_k$$
$$\implies \sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k-\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}a_k-\sum_{k=n+21}^{\infty}a_k=\sum_{k=n}^{n+20}a_k$$
And I get stuck because even if I take the $n$-th root both sides I don't know if the left hand side is non negative.

My second try is that since $\sqrt[n]{\sum_{k=n}^{n+20}a_k} \to l$ as $n\to+\infty$ there exists $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $n>N$ implies $\sqrt[n]{\sum_{k=n}^{n+20}a_k}<\frac{l+1}{2}$, and so if $n>N$ then $0<\sum_{k=n}^{n+20}a_k<\left(\frac{l+1}{2}\right)^n$. Being $l<1$ and being $a_n>0$, we deduce $\lim_{n \to +\infty} \sum_{k=n}^{n+20}a_k=0$. But I can't conclude using this.

Answer (score 1):

Choose $t$ such that $l<t<1$. From $\lim_{n}\sqrt[n]{\sum_{k=n}^{n+20}a_{k}}=l<t$,
we can choose $N$ such that $\sqrt[n]{\sum_{k=n}^{n+20}a_{k}}<t$
whenever $n\geq N$. In particular, $a_{n}\leq\sum_{k=n}^{n+20}a_{k}<t^{n}$.
Now, $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_{n}=\sum_{n=1}^{N-1}a_{n}+\sum_{n=N}^{\infty}a_n\leq\sum_{n=1}^{N-1}a_{n}+\sum_{n=N}^{\infty}t^{n}<\infty$.
Therefore, the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_{n}$ is convergent.